# Preposition with traveling

Tags: prepositions

I have a question about how to use or if I can use the word traveling  together with 'with' preposition.

> Number of commuters spending more than two hours travelling to and from work up by 72% in last decade.

Is it possible to use with in the sentence above?

And how about this:

> I am traveling to Beijing tomorrow and coming back in 5 days. I should have booked a longer stay since one day will go with traveling there and an another with coming back.

Thanks in advance
Tom

Comment: Where would you put the word "with" in your first example?

Comment: Number of commuters spending more than two hours with travelling to and from work up by 72% in last decade

Comment: One day will go to travelling there and another [will go] to coming back. No withs anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult simply to insert "with" in the first sentence.

In the case of the second, the use of "with" is perfectly alright, but "go" does not sound quite right.

It would be more usual to say ***...one day will be taken up with travelling there and another with coming back.***

Comment: "Dee studied eighteen hours each day, spent two hours eating and four hours sleeping". In this sentence,similarly to my original question,there are two words without prepositions.According to your answer," with" can be used in certain circumstances but I do not know when it is preferred.I have also come across words using "in" prepositions such as this:"We spent two hours in eating only  ..."

Comment: @proftom Use of prepositions with verbs is very difficult to learn by rule. So much is idiomatic, and you pick up idioms through use and experience. It is difficult for me to be of general help as I am a native speaker and just know these things naturally. But there must be some recommended learning material on prepositions, isn't there?